# Android rectangle background gradient

Tags: android, background, gradient

I want to crate a background gradient that goes from the inside to outside. And at the outside it should be getting darker. Here is an image:

[image]

Can anyone give me some advice how I can create something like that? 
Or should I take an image for this? If yes, what's about different screen resolutions? Or about landscape / portrait modus?

Comment: If you are using nine patch image then when you rotate your screen at a time it can be some issue but if you are using xml file it will never create issue.. so as per my view you have to achieve this functionality using gradient (.xml) file. @MyNewName

Answer (score 5):

use this change color as required

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <gradient
        android:type="radial"
        android:startColor="#f15330"
        android:endColor="#da0000"
        android:gradientRadius="150dp"
        />
   <size android:height="400dp"
       android:width="250dp"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

How you want is it like cardview?Or you can try with this also,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <gradient
                android:angle="360"
                android:centerColor="#e95a22"
                android:endColor="#ff00b5"
                android:gradientRadius="360"
                android:startColor="#006386"
                android:type="sweep" />

            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#ff207d94" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:top="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#fff" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can use [nine patch image](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html#&sourceDensity=160&name=example) to achieve for this type gredient

but if you want use gredient then i think this will be help for you..

```
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <gradient 
    android:type="radial"
    android:centerX="50%" 
    android:centerY="50%" 
    android:startColor="#FFff0000" 
    android:endColor="#FF000000" 
    android:gradientRadius="100"/>
</shape>
```

and [this](http://angrytools.com/gradient/) is olnline tool where you can create gredient and you can grab the code using android tab..

Comment: If you are using nine patch image then when you rotate your screen at a time it can be some issue but if you are using xml file it will never create issue.. so as per my view you have to achieve this functionality using gradient (.xml) file. @MyNewName